# Turn data-attribute array into object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, custom-data-attribute

I'm setting an array using an HTML5 `data` attribute like this: `<dl data-options='[{ "multiExpand": true} ]'>`
And grabbing it with jQuery like so: `var options = $this.data('options')[0]`

It works, but I'm hoping to eliminate the need for the brackets in the markup. I'm wanting to be able to write `<dl data-options="multiExpand: true; otherOption: false;">`

How do I need to change up the JS to grab it in that format? I've been trying `.makeArray` and `.toJSON` but they return `undefined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you really need is valid JSON in the attribute, and jQuery will convert it to an object

```
<dl data-options='{"multiExpand":true,"otherOption":false}'>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7v9pT/)

If you just have to use that invalid syntax, you have to parse it yourself, something like

```
var arr = $('#test').data('options').split(';').filter(Boolean),
    obj = (function() {
        var o = {};
        $.each(arr, function(_,v) {
            var parts = v.split(':');
            o[$.trim(parts[0])] = $.trim(parts[1]);
        });
        return o;
    }());
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7v9pT/1/)

Comment: Assuming your dl is as you want it:

    <dl data-options="multiExpand: true; otherOption: false;">

Otherwise you'll have an array with a single object inside of an object.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was hoping to not have to parse it myself (like there would be a magic jQuery method for this) but it looks like that's my only option if I want the `data-options` syntax without the brackets.